# JavaScript parser in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, parsing

I need to add some lightweight syntactic sugar to JavaScript source code, and process it using a JavaScript-based build system. Are there any open source JavaScript parsers written in JavaScript? And are they reasonably fast when run on top of V8 or a similar high-performance JavaScript implementation?

Thank you for any pointers you can provide!

Comment: "I need to add some lightweight syntactic sugar to JavaScript source code"  You do?  Like what?

Comment: you need it for code exposition or for editor?

Comment: Objective-J does that. you might want to checkout its open sourced code. But it uses a totally different syntax similar to Objective-C and interprets to Javascript at runtime afaik.

Comment: JSLint contains a JavaScript parser written in JavaScript. See http://www.jslint.com/fulljslint.js Around line 2049 begins the parser. JSLint is written to also handle html so you'd have to gloss over those parts.

Comment: Crescent French: Please repost your comment as an answer, and I'll vote you up. Thank you!

Comment: The source code for jslint is available on GitHub: https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSLint => https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSLint/blob/master/jslint.js

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Crescent Fresh answered this question in the comments:

> JSLint contains a JavaScript parser written in JavaScript. See [JSlint by Douglas Crockford](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSLint/blob/master/jslint.js) Around line 2712 begins the parser. JSLint is written to also handle html so you'd have to gloss over those parts

Comment: Crescent Fresh, if you'd like to repost your comment as an answer, I'll accept it and upvote you.

Comment: Recent source code, above link went 404: https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSLint

Comment: Answer updated (https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSLint/blob/master/jslint.js)

Answer (score 33):

[UglifyJS](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS) (JS compressor/beautifier in JavaScript) contains a complete JavaScript parser that exposes a simple API.  It's heavily tested and used in some big projects (WebKit).

Comment: UglifyJS is great and thank you for it. Thanks also for HTMLArea, which was a great reference for me when developing a WYSIWYG editor around 7 or 8 years ago. I would suggest mentioning your interest when linking to UglifyJS though.

Comment: I'd just like to point out that this parser is ready to go, and seems to work perfectly. It's contained in a separate file, so no need to wade through jslint.js to take out parts you don't need. +1

Answer (score 25):

The [fastest](http://esprima.org/test/compare.html) Javascript parser in Javascript was [esprima](http://esprima.org/).

It also gives you

> Sensible format for the abstract syntax tree (AST), compatible with Mozilla Parser API

Answer (score 13):

[acorn](http://marijnhaverbeke.nl/acorn/) is a really fast JavaScript parser written in JavaScript. It's even faster than [esprima](http://esprima.org/) now. The results I got in Chrome form [esprima's speed comparison page](http://esprima.org/test/compare.html):

```
Source            Esprima    UglifyJS2    Traceur    Acorn
Underscore 1.4.1  15.1       23.8         14.2       7.6
Backbone 1.0.0    17.1       30.2         16.7       7.9
jQuery 1.9.1      241.1      247.2        125.4      81.4
Total             273.3 ms   301.2 ms     156.3 ms   96.9 ms
```

It's compatible with Mozilla's Parser API, so you can use [escodegen](https://github.com/Constellation/escodegen) to generate JavaScript from the parse trees.

Answer (score 9):

It's not a JavaScript parser itself, but there's a project called [Jison](http://zaach.github.com/jison/) (like Bison) for generating parsers that's written in JS.

Comment: Well, the question **was** for a JavaScript parser...??

Answer (score 7):

The only [metacircular interpreter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metacircular_interpreter) that I have seen implemented in JavaScript is the [Narcissus](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla/source/js/narcissus/) Engine.

It was developed also by Brendan Eich, they used a lot of non-standard extensions that are specific to *SpiderMonkey*, I think it will not work on V8.

Comment: Interesting! I suppose there's a parser hiding in there somewhere. :-) Unfortunately, I'm looking for something that runs under V8. But thanks for the very interesting link!

Answer (score 6):

Microsoft has developed the TypeScript compiler in TypeScript. Since TypeScript is a strict superset of JavaScript, and TypeScript compiles to JavaScript, the resulting compiler is technically a JavaScript compiler written in JavaScript.

That of course depends upon your definition of "compiler". But if a compiler accepting a superset of language A is not a language A compiler, that excludes GCC, Clang and pretty much every other compiler.

Answer (score 3):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/SpiderMonkey/Parser_API:

> Recent builds of the standalone SpiderMonkey shell include a
>   reflection of the SpiderMonkey parser, made available as a JavaScript
>   API.

Note that this is only an API in JavaScript, the parser is C++.

Answer (score 0):

JS/CC - The LALR(1) parser and lexical analyzer generator for JavaScript, written in JavaScript - http://jscc.phorward-software.com/

Comment: Link works since latest edit