# JavaScript parser written in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Does anyone know of a JavaScript parser written JavaScript itself?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript parser in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2554519/javascript-parser-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla/source/js/narcissus/

Narcissus. Enjoy!