# In JavaScript, how do I split a string based on conditions within that string?

Tags: javascript, regex, string

### Background

I am currently writing a function which needs to accept a command as a string.  The string needs to be split into it's finer parts so that the function may then use those parts.  Here is an example string:

`People.filter(Hometown.eq("Pittsburgh"))`

Which, in this *simplified* example, I would need to resolve to something like:

```
var objectToTraverse = "People";
var actionToTake = "filter";
var comparer = "Hometown";
var targetValue = "Pittsburgh";
```

For the example above, the split operation is fairly easy:

```
var _command = "People.filter(Hometown.eq("Pittsburgh"))";
var command = _command.split(".");

var objectToTraverse = command[0];
var actionToTake = command[1].split("(")[0];
var comparer = command[1].split("(")[1];
var targetValue = command[2].split("(")[1].split(")")[0];
```

But what if you have a more complex command such as this:
`People.filter(Hometown.eq("Pittsburgh") && Gender.eq("male") || Age.eq(>= 35)).orderBy(Age,Gender).limitResultSet(10)`

The pattern may be different each time.

### Question

Using JavaScript, how do I efficiently parse a string-command based on various mixed delimiters and conditions such as this:

`People.filter(Hometown.eq("Pittsburgh") && Gender.eq("male") || Age.eq(>= 35)).orderBy(Age,Gender).limitResultSet(10)`

### Please Note

I am aware of all of the frameworks available already for querying data in JavaScript and, while I appreciate all tips and advice, I would still like an answer to this question regardless of what else is available out there.

Comment: Why not simply expose these objects to the user and then `eval()` on them to get the results? Then you dont need to parse anything.

Comment: I believe there are implementations of the javascript interpreter written in javascript, that's essentially what you are asking for.

Comment: @Tejs because `eval` is bad, mkay?!

Comment: @Tejs--Unless I am missing something, I can't `eval()` many of the commands I have in the example string since they are custom names.  So I would still have to parse the string and then map to the appropriate JS commands, correct?

Comment: @Alnitak Sure, but if the user is silly enough to `eval()` themselves into a horrible spot, they have no one to blame but themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex, particularly JavaScript's flavor of regex which lacks recursion and balanced groups, is not up to the task of parsing code like this. Your sample code, with its well-formed nested parentheses, is a classic example of a [context-free grammar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar), which [far wiser men than I](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1758162/399649) have declared undoable with regex.

What you need is an actual parser. There are [full JavaScript parsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2554519/javascript-parser-in-javascript) available that are, themselves, implemented in JavaScript ([JSLint](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSLint/blob/master/jslint.js) has one in it). Or, if you only want to allow certain types of expressions, you can [generate a parser to suit any grammar you choose](http://pegjs.majda.cz/).

**One thing to be aware of:** This is definitely doable with a parser (albeit not with regex alone). But it's unlikely to be easy or simple. If this is for a real-world project, unless you have a driving reason to write your own markup/programming language, I suggest you consider using an existing solution. If you're describing *expressions* rather than imperative code (e.g. LINQ vs. classic C#), XML or JSON could be good ways to do it.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to sensibly parse this is with (wait for it...) a *parser*!

See http://javascript.crockford.com/tdop/tdop.html for Douglas Crockford's take on how to write parsers in Javascript.