# JS: finding regexp literals in code

Tags: javascript, regex, parsing

I'm parsing some JavaScript code and need to get all the regular expressions in it. The literal notation `/\/(.(?:[^\/])|\\)+\/[gmi]*/gi` looks good, but in some cases it works incorrectly.

For example, for this code:

```
html = html.replace(/\</g, '&lt;').replace(/\>/g, '&gt;').replace(/\&/g, '&amp;');
```

match() gives two stupid results: `/\</g, '&lt;' ).replace( /` and `/\&/g`

I can't seem to make it work.

Comment: I recommend to use an actual JavaScript parser like http://esprima.org/. Then you can walk the AST and get all regular expression literals easily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will not get away with this using a single regex. You've now stumbled upon a single corner case which your regex doesn't handler properly, but there are many, many more. Your regex will break when there's an opening regexp literal inside a multi- or single-line comment, or when a `/` occurs inside a string literal.

The only when to reliably solve this would be to parse the JavaScript, and inspect the token stream the parser (or lexer) produces.

To get started, see: [JavaScript parser in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2554519/javascript-parser-in-javascript)

> ***user3371384 wrote:***
>
> *I don't care about comments, because I remove them before getting regexp literals, same about strings.*

Regardless, there are more corner cases:

```
var e = 8, f = 4, g = 2;
// ...
var x = e/f/g; // your regex will match `/f/g` as a regex literal
```

> ***user3371384 wrote:***
>
> *In many code parsers the same algorythm is used: find slash, then find next slash (if no backslash before it), all chars inside is regexp.*

That may well be, but that is a very inaccurate algorithm (as you can see by the counter example I gave above). There's also the shorthand `/=` that might foul up the regex.

Anyway, you seem to have made up your mind about using a regex for this...

You placed the `.` in the wrong place: you only want to match any char *after* the backslash. Try this:

```
/\/([^\/]|\\.)+\/[gmi]*/gi
```

Comment: ... or whereever the regexp has nested parentheses representing a sub-regular expression.  The real point is the notation of regular expressions, is not itself regular.  Rather, it is context-free.  OP is trying to recognize a context-free construct with regular expressions, always doomed to failure.  Yes, he needs a real parser.

Comment: I don't care about comments, because I remove them before getting regexp literals, same about strings. The problem is getting regexp literal from code [where no comments and strings].

Comment: In many code parsers the same algorythm is used: find slash, then find next slash (if no backslash before it), all chars inside is regexp. This is good enough algorythm for my purposes, and `/\/(.(?:[^\/])|\\)+\/[gmi]*/gi` seems correct, but not in fact. What wrong there?

Comment: Thank you Bart, I convinced you absolutely right. This is complicated issue needs complicated solution.