# Substring extraction from stringified Javascript function

Tags: javascript, replace, extract

I need to extract the id `pKmuXgem` from the following function (being returned as a string):

`"someFunction('Short Description','','pKmuXgem'); return false;"`

The id may change, but the surrounding markup should stay the same. I can do a simple string replace:

```
var str = "someFunction('Short Description','','pKmuXgem'); return false;";
var id = str.replace("someFunction('Short Description','','", "");
id = str.replace("'); return false;", "");
```

but that feels fragile.

What is best practice?

Comment: [JavaScript parser in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2554519/javascript-parser-in-javascript) would be bullet-proof solution...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use RegEx.

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rcdgy2to/1/)

```
var data = "someFunction('Short Description','','pKmuXgem'); return false;";
var match = /,'([^']+?)'\)/g.exec(data);
console.log(match[1]);
```

Comment: This assumes there are only `[a-zA-Z]` in the string.  Why?  It could be anything except a single quote.