# Convert a string that looks like an array into an actual array

Tags: javascript

If I have `str = "[[1,Warriors,NBA],[2,Kings,NBA],[3,Knicks,NBA]]"` how could I turn that into a array in JavaScript?

An array where each element of the array is an array itself.

Possible?

Comment: Why not just create an array to begin with, or at least valid JSON

Comment: If this is the content format you're stuck with, then you will have to write your own parser that understands that format.  There is no pre-built way to parse this non-standard format.

Comment: What is source of this string? Making it valid json at source would help

Comment: It is something that is being passed in as is

Comment: I think I will explore making it into valid JSON and going from there... thx. Though I am curious if the above can be turned into an actual array.

Comment: How would you convert `Warriors` in javascript?  Is it referring to a variable or a string?

Comment: I need to be able to update a select in a form dynamically. I think I will try to transform it to JSON first and then go from there

Comment: `var arr = [[1,"Warriors","NBA"],[2,"Kings","NBA"],[3,"Knicks","NBA"]];`

Comment: Parsing the string isn't too hard if the format is a simple as the OP. Have a go and if you have any issues, post questions about that.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this rudimentary function I put together for 2D arrays:

```js
function customParse(data){
    arr = []
    for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
      if(str[i] == ','){
        if(!isNaN(str[i-1])){
          arr.push(',')
          arr.push('"')
        }else{
          if(str[i-1] != "]"){
            arr.push('"')
            arr.push(',')
            arr.push('"')
          }else{
            arr.push(',')
          }
        }
      }else{
        if(str[i] == ']' && str[i-1] != ']'){
          arr.push('"')
        }
        arr.push(str[i])
      }
    }
    return JSON.parse(arr.join(""))
}

str = "[[1,Warriors,NBA],[2,Kings,NBA],[3,Knicks,NBA]]"
result = customParse(str)
alert("Raw: "+result);
alert("Stringified: "+JSON.stringify(result));
```

Answer (score 2):

A little dirty, but will do the trick. the "matches" variable would contain your array of arrays.

```
var str = "[[1,Warriors,NBA],[2,Kings,NBA],[3,Knicks,NBA]]";
var cleanStr = str.substring(1,str.length-1)

var matches = [];

var pattern = /\[(.*?)\]/g;
var match;

while ((match = pattern.exec(cleanStr)) != null)
{
  matches.push(match[1].split(","));
}
```

Additionally, if you have the option, just define the array in javascript.

```
var list = [[1,'Warriors','NBA'],['2','Kings','NBA'],[3,'Knicks','NBA']];
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some javascript parsers written in javascript. See this:[JavaScript parser in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2554519/javascript-parser-in-javascript), this:https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS, this:http://esprima.org/, this:http://marijnhaverbeke.nl/acorn/.

Comment: This isn't an answer, it should be a comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
var array = JSON.parse("[" + str + "]");
```

or you can use  `.split()`, that will also end up with an Array of strings.