# Convert String into method arguments, specifically in console.log

Tags: javascript, regex

I am working on a problem where I need to ensure whether a particular argument is present in calls to `console.log` throughout in my code base. Simply speaking the main objective would be add that argument if not present.

In my initial approach, I am extracting the list of parameters to `console.log(...)` and thinking of making it into any array somehow (I am not sure how. I wish to make it reliable enough like closing braces, commas can be inside a string as a parameter to function etc.).

A complex instance would be

```
console.log("this is a string,another()",'single \'quote\'',param1, param['key'+some_variable]);
```

So any approach or suggestion to help me going.

Comment: Could you please clarify: the input is `var s = 'console.log("this is a string,another()",\'single \'quote\'\',param1, param[\'key\'+some_variable]);'`? See https://jsfiddle.net/2L1dtzgh/

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - This is amazing and correct according to my requirement. Are you sure if this would hold correct for all cases ? I got one case to worry i.e. if my first param is "this is string ); contains closing braces of console.log". Any hint ?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by the edge case. Can you have `console.log("this is string);` where `"this is string);` is the value you need?

Comment: more likely console.log("this is a string ); and it contains edge case.",param1); So I should get "this is a string ); and it contains edge case." as first param and param1 as second. Only thing is if we get the regex that determine console start/end within a string as a param.

Comment: The point is that the `console.log(` is removed from the start, and `);` from the end. With the above input, I get `[
  "\"this is a string ); and it contains edge case.\"",
  "param1"
]` array.

Comment: You are right indeed. I misrepresented some stuff. I need to extract the whole console.log statement from a file to process with your solution. So I am using console.log\([^\)]+\); as regex. Hence this wouldn't work in the above case. That is what I am worried about.

Comment: *that argument if not present* What argument do you want to add?

Comment: You have not indicated you need to extract the `console.log(...);`  from the larger string in the question. That will make the code a bit longer, since you cannot use a tempered greedy token, but you may use my regex to build the whole `console.log();` regex and then parse it with my solution.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - got your point. Thanks for helping out.

Comment: Actually, it is rather fragile to use the regex to actually get the `console.log` line of code from a larger code. You should think of parsing the code with some parser rather than a regex.

Comment: You should override `console.log` and check for the extra parameter you want at runtime. I would provide an example if you could tell me what argument you want to check for and add.

Comment: @torazaburo - I am in fact overriding console.log for a purpose but I need that extra parameter from the declaration. For this I am going through the trouble to ensure that the extra param is present in every console.

Comment: Which extra parameter? By "declaration" do you mean "invocation"? Show the desired result based on your sample code.

Comment: Yes and It's somewhat related to context and there is no alternatives. Thanks.

Comment: If it's related to context then how are you going to know what parameter to add even after you've parsed the call? What are you going to do with the elements in the array that Wiktor's regexp gives you? There are no alternatives to what?

Comment: I am gonna add a parameter like (param ? param : null) and I know most section of my invoking methods would have the same variable defined.

Comment: How many of these do you need to fix? You're best off just grepping through your source for `console.log` and fixing them manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**NOTE**: The code and regex patterns below are good to use for parsing a single `console.log` line as input. When you need to parse the whole code, you need to check [JavaScript parser in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2554519/javascript-parser-in-javascript).

You can use a  2  step approach: remove the `console.log(` from the start and `);` from the end with a `replace`, and then use `match` with a regex to extract each single argument that can be either a double- or single-quoted string literal or a plain variable with no comma inside.

You may use

```js
var s = 'console.log(/s[\\\\\\/]/g,a/b,`${`foobar, and more foobar`}`,"this is a string,another()",\'single \\\'quote\\\'\',param1, param[\'key\'+some_variable],`"\\` and more`);';
console.log(s.replace(/^console\.log\(|\);$/g,'').match(/\/(?:\\.|[^\\\/])+\/[gim]*|`\${`[^`\\]*(?:\\.[^\\`]*)*`}`|(?:"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^\\"]*)*"|'[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^\\']*)*'|`[^`\\]*(?:\\.[^\\`]*)*`|[^,])+/g));
```

The main pattern **to parse the string *inside* `console.log()`** is

```
/\/(?:\\.|[^\\\/])+\/[gim]*|`\${`[^`\\]*(?:\\.[^\\`]*)*`}`|(?:"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^\\"]*)*"|'[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^\\']*)*'|`[^`\\]*(?:\\.[^\\`]*)*`|[^,])+/g
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hD6fU4/3).

**Pattern details**:

- `^console\.log\(` - `console.log(` string at the string start
- `|` - or
- `\);$` - `);` at the string end

and

- `\/(?:\\.|[^\\\/])+\/[gim]*` - attempts to match a regex literal (those that start with `/`, then may have 1 or more non-`/` or `\`+any char and can have any `g`, `i`, or `m` combinations after the trailing `/`
- `` `\${`[^`\\]*(?:\\.[^\\`]*)*`}` `` - matches specific template string syntax
- `(?:"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^\\"]*)*"|'[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^\\']*)*'|[^,'"]+)+` - 1 or more sequences of:

  - `"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^\\"]*)*"` - a `"` followed with 0+ chars other than `\` and `"`, followed with 0+ sequences of a `\` + any char but a newline followed with 0+ chars other than `\` and `"` (a double quoted literal pattern)
  - `|'[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^\\']*)*'` - or the similar pattern as above but with single quotes
  - `` |`[^`\\]*(?:\\.[^\\`]*)*` `` - a template string literal pattern similar to the above
  - `|[^,'"]+` - or 1 or more chars other than `,`, `"`, `'`.

Comment: This is mind-bogglingly horrible. Are you going to move on now to write a JS parser in regexp?

Comment: @torazaburo: No, that is not the point, this is a good regex following the unroll-the-loop technique and it can parse the singl- or double-quoted string literals well in a well-formed string. I just did not consider that the `console.log();` might appear inside a longer text. Then, it makes little sense to use a regex to parse the whole code, sure.

Comment: This fails if the parameter is `/,/`.

Comment: It also fails on a template string containing a quote mark.

Comment: Hi @torazaburo: As for the regex literal, agreed, I added a disclaimer. I do not get the last comment about the quote mark though - it does match if there is a `console.log('"');` input

Comment: I applaud your virtuosity in crafting this regexp, and there are good lessons to be learned from it. So thanks. But it's a little bit odd to give an answer which doesn't really solve the OP's problem (apparently to fix **all** the `console.log`s in his program, not just match one), and still doesn't work in all cases, although one could say it solves it in the sense that it works for the cases he gave.

Comment: I was trying to say that a parameter of the form `\`"\`` doesn't work. In other words, a template string, delimited by backticks.

Comment: @torazaburo: Well, at leat template string literals are syntactically similar to other literal types. I added it as an alternative branch. I can actually think of adding the regex literals, too, but just do not have much time for it now. BTW, I posted this only because OP said it worked for OP.

Comment: Unfortunately, you have run out of gas in trying to parse JS with regexps, because the following is a valid template string which your new logic won't handle properly: `\`${\`foobar\`}\``.

Comment: Well, it does not matter what I will finally come to, I will update this answer in the future.

Comment: @torazaburo: I actually updated the regex since [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/) looks unable to parse the template string literal provided by you last. I tried with `console.log(/s[\\\/]/g,a/b,
\`${\`foobar\`}\`,
\`${\`foobar, and more foobar\`}\`,
"this is a string,another()",
'single \'quote\'',param1, param['key'+some_variable],\`"\\` and more\`);`

Comment: That seems to be a bug in JSLint. Chrome, Babel, and TypeScript all parse it without complaining. I've reported it to the maintainer. For reference, the exact string I tried was `var x = \`${\`${1}\`}\`;`.